# +100 rep for account association -- what are the conditions?

Tags: support, reputation

Today I got 100 reputation points for 'account association' and I'm not sure why. I joined MathOverflow and SuperUser *long* before I found out Math.SE even existed, and I've been on that site for a few weeks now, so I'm puzzled.

In general, what are the conditions for these rep points -- are they only in relation to particular Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: You might want to see if this has been asked on meta.SO.

Comment: My understanding is that you have to have at least one other StackExchange-network account (so MO wouldn't count) with 200+ rep to get the linking bonus.  I can't, however, see why you would have gotten the linking bonus today, unless you either just linked the accounts today or your SU account went over 200 rep and somehow back under.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You crossed 200 points on your Math.SE account today. That's the first account (on the SE network) where you've passed 200 points, so the bonus was awarded to all associated accounts (you went from 242 to 342 on Math.SE, and 90 to 190 on SU).

(BTW: I just recalculated your reputation on Math.SE, since you were 5 points over what it should have been - so if you notice the drop from 347, don't worry)

Comment: D'oh, I forgot to account for the +100 when I was looking to see if he crossed 200 somewhere.

Comment: Is this the only possibility to get a bonus?

Comment: @draks: you can answer a [featured](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) question and potentially win a bonus / bounty that way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Association Bonus"...

Comment: @draks: then no, you get an association bonus on all current and future site-profiles once you gain 200 points on one site - that's the only criteria for getting that bonus.